# Is the character of Randolph Henry Ash based on any particular Victorian poet?

Tags: character-analysis, inspiration

The novel *Possession* contains some spot-on mimicry of several different writing styles, including lengthy poems by two fictional Victorian poets. The character of RH Ash in particular feels as if there is some model, or models, for him. He has a very distinct style and a distinct set of interests (including naturalism and Greek and Norse myths).

Is he similar to Tennyson, or Browning, or some other real poet, or an amalgam?  Or is he purely Byatt's creation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possession_(Byatt_novel)#Background) makes a claim, apparently based on this article by the [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/1990/10/21/books/unearthing-the-secret-lover.html), that Randolph Henry Ash is based on Robert Browning and/or Alfred Lord Tennyson.

Not having read the book, I can't really offer any further commentary.

Comment: I caught an interview with the author the other day (http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/specials/133_wbc_archive_new/page2.shtml) which confirms the article's thoughts: Ash is based on Browning and Tennyson, and LaMotte is based on Rosetti (as well as Dickinson).

Comment: When I read the book, I assumed he was based on Browning. But I probably just missed the similarities with Tennyson.